# Is Bluetooth Profile A2DP and SPP used for recording audio from a Bluetooth Microphone?

Tags: android, react-native, bluetooth

**I will update this question with the code within 5 hours**. I need your help answering this question:

1. Can you pair a bluetooth device with 2 react native library?

   ```
   One with SPP bluetooth profile and the other with A2DP bluetooth profile. If not, I plan to write the Android native module
   ```

My goal is to support a Bluetooth Microphone for my React Native app. I intent to only support Android for the MVP.

**What I have did:**

1. I use `react-native-bluetooth-classic` for Serial Port Profile (SPP).

   The output

   ```
   CR is ASCII char code 13.
   LF is ASCII char code 10.

   There is 4 buttons, each button send a ASCII characters with CR or LF ending:
   1. Push to talk button
      When pressing the button => C:BRGIN*${CR}+=GPIO=1${CR}${LF}
      When releasing the button => C:END*${CR}+=GPIO=0${CR}${LF}
   2. Select Group Up
      C:VM*${CR}
   3. Select Group Down
      C:VP*${CR}
   4. SOS Button
      C:SOS*${CR}
   ```

**What should I do?:**

1. Write an android native module to pair a bluetooth device with SPP and A2DP. I have no prior experience writing a Android Native Module, I will be following [React Native Android Native Module tutorial](https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-android)
2. Use [`react-native-bluetooth-classic`](https://github.com/kenjdavidson/react-native-bluetooth-classic/) for the SPP bluetooth profile and use [`react-native-a2dp`](https://github.com/microCloudCode/react-native-a2dp/) for the AVRCP bluetooth profile.

I plan to test the `react-native-a2dp` today. I am not sure whether I can pair to a Bluetooth device using 2 react-native library. I will keep this post updated.

Sincerely,
kidfrom

**Edit**

For those who is looking for similar use case.

If you do care about the minSdkVersion, you should build your own native module, `react-native-bluetooth-classic` require minSdkVersion 26 which is in my use case significantly reduce my target market share. But If you ask my opinion, currently I still use `react-native-bluetooth-classic` and `react-native-a2dp` for the MVP.

**If you don't:**

Either you can use `react-native-bluetooth-classic` + `react-native-a2dp` library or build your own native module. For my case using the combined library is good enough for the MVP. Although the minSdkVersion will be an issue in the future.

Comment: 1. You pair with device, not with service. 2. A2DP and SPP are different Bluetooth profiles, not a parts of each other. 3. A2DP defines L2CAP control channel, not RFCOMM one. 4. HFP profile defines RFCOMM control channel. 5. Probably your device has separate SPP profile, but it is not a part of A2DP.

Comment: Hey, how did the testing go?  I'm curious, and also if you feel like `react-native-bluetooth-classic` would benefit from the addition of profiles, I definitely don't mind discussing and accepting a pull request.   You might want to look at https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-audio-record, for starting a recording when the appropriate AT command comes in.

Comment: @kendavidson I used your project `react-native-bluetooth-classic` and `react-native-a2dp` library. Thank you, it works as expected. The usage as follows: `connectToDevice` + `startBluetoothSco` to record, and `stopBluetoothSco` to stop.

Comment: @kendavidson sorry for the missed deadline to add a PR `which I promise to get back within a week but I did not, sorry`. I hope I can get back here within a month. I am building the back end side now since `react-native-bluetooth-classic` and `react-native-a2dp` is good enough for the MVP.

Comment: @MikePetrichenko Thanks for clearing it up. `The app pair with the device not the SPP and/or A2DP`. Is it correct? The first step of leveraging a bluetooth is to `connect to the device` -> `start the service e.g createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord for SPP and startBluetoothSco for A2DP` -> listen to the data sent by the bluetooth device.

Comment: Usualy (it depends on device but usualy) A2DP requires pairing. That does not mean that profile requires pairing (ok, in fact there are 2 "pairing level" but to be simple think only about device). So first step is to pair with your device. Next step is to connect to A2DP profile control channel. I do not remember exactly (it can be found in A2DP specification) but A2DP may require some initiale sequence, so your application must send/receive/answer some initial commands. Next you can open audio link. And again, A2DP control channel is not RFCOMM based. It is L2CAP based.

Comment: Did you solve your problem?  If so, you should post your solution as an answer, rather than edit it into your question.